# Flex/Coldfusion Remoting issue. - 'Destination ColdFusion does not exist'

Tags: apache-flex, iis, coldfusion-9, remoteobject

I'm trying to resolve a Flex remote object Coldfusion call. I'm getting the following error.

**[MessingError message='Destination 'ColdFusion' either does not exist or the destination has no channels defined (and the application does not define any default channels.)']**

When I access my CFC through a cfm page, they work. Due to the way the servers are configured, I'm having issues setting up flex with a coldfusion service when I create a new project because I'm developing on a machine, but have to push everything to the server where CF is located.  I'm also wondering if the way CF is setup may be an issue. The company is running Coldfusion from the c:\inetpub directory with IIS and out of the same webroot directory they are running WordPress/MySQL (6 WP sites to be exact). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I will also add that when I create the flex project I can not set ColdFusion as the web server whether local (1.This machine doesn't run a local instance due to office permissions) and 2.) They don't have the J2EE setup.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is what you get when you go to: http://www.domain.com/flex2gateway. That should give you a blank page, but if you get anything else (such as a 404) the flex gateway isn't running.

The other thing to make sure is that you set your services compiler argument on flash builder to the coldfusion services-config.xml file in the WEB-INF/flex directory.

```
-services c:/Coldfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml
```

Comment: I checked your first recommendation. I got a blank page when I went to the domain with /flex2gateway.

But when I compile my flex app, I don't have the web-inf/flex folder

Comment: Can you grab the file from your server and place it locally so you can compile with it?

Comment: I have access to the server. Where would I find it?

Comment: It is usually in cf_root/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml. Alternatively if you can't find it, you can always download and install a local cf server and get the file after installation in your web root. Unless you guys are using something custom in your flex gateway it should work the same.

Comment: Did you ever find the file?

Comment: Not yet, I will be diggng for it tomorrow when I get in.

Comment: Just copied the folder over into my flex project.

Comment: Do you know how to add compiler arguments to Flash builder? If not, "You can modify the default Flex compiler or ActionScript compiler settings that Flash builder uses. To view or modify the default settings, from the Flash Builder menu, select Project > Properties, and then select Flex Compiler or ActionScript Compiler, as required." http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fef.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fe7

Comment: Thank you. I'm about to dig into this one this morning. I've just been bounced around projects so I didn't have a chance to finish resolving this issue.

Comment: On the compiler argument being -services c:/Coldfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml, do I set that where it says Additional compiler arguments. In that field I have -locale en_US.

Comment: Still having issues. I copied the file over, but flex won't allow a release build for me to test on the server due to: unable to open 'c:/Coldfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml'.

Comment: That was just an example path, use whatever the path is on your machine. I believe there is also referenced files inside services-config.xml (remoting-config.xml if I remember right) so make sure those are there as well.. Open the file with a text editor and verify

Comment: I don't have coldfusion running on my local machine. I have to code then push it to the server to test. Local instances of coldfusion are not permitted on the machines.

Comment: By path on your machine I meant path to the services-config.xml file, you don't need coldfusion locally

Comment: Got that. Changed it. Now I'm getting a "the services configuration include a channel-definition 'cf-polling-amf' that has an endpoint with a context.root token, but a context root has not been defined. I had the same message for java polling so I commented out the java polling one as I assume I don't need a java polling channel definition.